# Custom Django form not posting

Tags: python, html, django

I am very new to Django and was creating a small project to learn it. I am trying to make a form that users can add text and submit it to create a post, sort of like a tweet. The CSRF_token shows up in the url bar and so does the text that I want posted, meaning it's being sent like a GET request for some reason. Here is my code so far, I've commented out a bunch of things that I was testing or don't work:

views.py:

```
def home(response):
    userInfo = response.user
    rants = userRants.objects.all()
    # form = makeRant(response.POST)
    print("response is type:" + response.method)
    # print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%x"))
    print(response.POST)
    if response.method == "POST":
        # if form.is_valid():
        print(response.POST.get(rantTextArea))
        inpRantDate = datetime.datetime.now()
        # t = userRants(username = userInfo.username, rantText = inpRantText, rantDate = inpRantDate)
        # t.save()
        # response.user.userRants_set.create(username=userInfo.username, rantText=inpRantText)
        # print(inpRantText + " " + inpRantDate + " " + userInfo.username)
        redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(response, "main/home.html", {"userInfo":userInfo, "userRants":rants})
```

home.html (form excerpt):

```
      <form type="POST" action="/home/" class="form">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="middleBarContainer">
            <div class="rantHeader">
               <span class="rantHeaderText">
               @{{userInfo.username}}
               </span>
            </div>
            <div class="rantBody">
               <textarea name="rantTextArea" id="rantTextArea" class="rantBodyTextInput" style="resize:none" placeholder="Enter RANT..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="rantDate">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submitRant">RANT!</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
```

models.py (excerpt):

```
class userRants(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rantText = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    rantDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.username, self.rantText, self.rantDate)
```

forms.py:

```
class makeRant(forms.Form):
    username = User.username
    rantText = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label="Enter RANT")
    rantDate = datetime.date.today()
```

The forms.py  form is not being used, but I included it just in case. Sorry for the amateur question, I have been trying to get this to work for a little bit and couldn't figure it out.

I've double checked to make sure the form method was POST, I've tried printing the response.POST but that shows nothing is getting posted. When the button gets clicked, it refreshes the page (normal) but doesn't POST the textarea.

EDIT: I've realized that the error is that it's supposed to be 'method=="POST"' when I had it as 'type="POST"'. A small error causing me lots of anguish.